# FadeOut optinon in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on site where when you get to a certain point in site, content fades in, and when I'm back above that point, it needs to fade out. I have worked my way to fade in, but when I scroll back up, it just disapperes without fade out. Can you please look at my code and tell me what did I do wrong?
HTML :

```
<body>
    <img src="pictures/placeholder1.jpg" id="first_image">
    <header>
      <img src="pictures/Norsein_logo_3.png">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">PROIZVODI</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">GALERIJA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">O NAMA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TIM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="maintext">
    </main>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  width : 100%;
  height: 15%;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:fixed;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 150;
}
header img{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 150;
}

main {
  height:2000px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  top: 100vh;
  background-image: url("pictures/background2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="%jQueryCDN"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
      $("header").css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)").fadeIn(1000);
      $("header img").css('visibility','visible').fadeIn(1000);
  } else {
    $("header").css("background", "transparent").fadeOut(1000);
    $("header img").css('visibility','hidden').fadeOut(1000);
  }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried else if with the reverse of the boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is the culprit

`$("header").css("background", "transparent").fadeOut(1000);`

did you see..

when you set `.css('background','transparent')` .. it  doesnt take any duration.. this is why your background disappears suddenly(changes background to tranparent)

you can actually remove that part to leave `$("header").fadeOut(1000);` only and it will work

Comment: nice explaination keep it going (y)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are hiding the element itself by visibility:hidden; then when fadeOut applies we can't really see it, because it was already hidden in a snap.

Here is you modified JS code, I hope it will work as intended.

```js
<script src="%jQueryCDN"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
      $("header").css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)").fadeIn(1000);
      $("header img").css('visibility','visible').fadeIn(1000);
  } else {
    $("header").fadeOut(1000);
    $("header img").fadeOut(1000);
  }
});
    </script>
```